# How to do dependency injection in Ember with Ember CLI?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

First, I made a small Ember app without Ember CLI.

I had this piece of code.

```
window.MyApp = Ember.Application.create({
  ready: function() {
    this.register('session:current', MyApp.SessionController, { singleton: true });
    this.inject('controller', 'session', 'session:current');
  }
});
```

This worked.

Then I decided to rewrite everything from scratch with Ember CLI.

I edited the file `app/app.js` and added the `ready` hook just like in my previous version.

```
var App = Ember.Application.extend({
  modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix,
  podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix,
  Resolver: Resolver,
  ready: function() {
    this.register('session:current', App.SessionController, { singleton: true });
    this.inject('controller', 'session', 'session:current');
  }
});
```

This doesn't work.

The session controller does exist. That's the content of the file `app/controllers/session.js`

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  isLoggedIn: false,
});
```

The error message I get is

```
TypeError: Attempting to register an unknown factory: `session:current`
```

It appears in the browser.

I googled that message, but I found nothing about dependency injection in Ember CLI.

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In ember-cli you can use `ember generate service <name of service>` and `ember generate initializer <name of initializer>` to build the stubs to achieve this, which is far better than fiddling about with `app.js`.

You create a service basically like this:

```
// app/services/notifications.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Object.extend({
  initNotifications: function() {
     // setup comes here
  }.on('init'),

  // Implementation snipped, not relevant to the answer.
});
```

And the initializer, which injects the service into the component(s) of your application which need it:

```
// app/initializers/notifications-service.js
import Notifications from '../services/notifications';

export default {
  name: 'notification-service',
  after: 'auth-service',

  initialize: function( container, app ) {
    app.register( 'notifications:main', Notifications, { singleton: true } );
    app.inject( 'component:system-notifications', 'notificationService', 'service:notifications' );
    app.inject( 'service:auth', 'notificationService', 'service:notifications' );
  }
};
```

With that, it becomes available as `notificationService` on the components specified.

Documentation on the subject of dependency injection in Ember can be found at http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/

Comment: What's the difference between a service and a initializer?

Comment: The service is simply the implementation of what you want to achieve. The initializer hooks in to the application startup, and allows you to run code at start up time (such as setting up and injecting your service) as initializers are loaded automatically, not on demand. This is much cleaner than hacking it in to app.js.

Comment: I ran `ember g service` and that also generate an initializer, so I guess I don't need to run `ember g initializer`?

Comment: Correct. It makes sense that it does, as a service isn't of much use without setting it up.