# ember-cli how to instantiate a view from within a controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am building an map single page app. I would like to be able to add or remove objects to the map retrieved by GEOJson data.

Some of these objects are to be presented as **<div>**
These objects are therefore not generated form a template but need to be instantiated somewhere else. I've been thinking of the controller in charge of parsing the GEOJson data.

What have I done so far?

**View**

```
//app/views/map-popup.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: "mapPopup",
  classNames: ["map-popup"]
});
```

**Template**

```
// app/templates/map-popup.js
<a class="popup-closer" {{action 'closePopup'}}></a>
<div class="popup-header">{{header}}</div>
<div class="popup-content">{{body}}</div>
```

**Controller**

```
//app/controllers/map-popup.js
/**
 * Created by alex on 13/04/2015.
 */
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['map'],
  feature: null,
  header: null,
  body: null,
  overlay: null,

  /**
   * Create an overlay to anchor the popup to the map.
   */
  createOverlay: function() {
    return new ol.Overlay(/** @type {olx.OverlayOptions} */ ({
      autoPan: true,
      autoPanAnimation: {
        duration: 250
      }
    }));
  },

  hide: function() {
    this.overlay.setPosition(undefined);
  },

  addToMap: function() {
    var map = this.get('controllers.map.map');
    this.overlay = this.createOverlay();
    map.addOverlay(this.overlay);
  },

  actions: {
    closePopup: function() {
      this.hide();
    }
  }
});
```

I was thinking about something like this in the controller:

```
//app/controllers/map-draw.js
//... some code ...//
var popup = this.get('mapPopup').create({feature: this.sketch});
this.get('popups').pushObject(popup);
popup.addToMap();
//... some more code ...//
```

I've read a lot about dependency injection, lookup etc.

- ["How to dynamically load ember components by name in a template?"](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-dynamically-load-ember-components-by-name-in-a-template/6312)
- [Programmatically rendering ember components](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/programmatically-rendering-ember-components/6986)
- [DEPENDENCY INJECTION & SERVICE LOOKUP](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/)
- [How to do dependency injection in Ember with Ember CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932790/how-to-do-dependency-injection-in-ember-with-ember-cli)

The later one is promising, but I find a bit overkill to create an initializer to inject a view in a single controller. What do you think about it?

**EDIT: Some trying with the 4th solution**

I added an initializer:

```
//app/initializers/map-popup-service.js

export function initialize(container, application ) {
  application.inject( 'controller:map-draw', 'mapPopup', 'view:map-popup' );
}

export default {
  name: 'map-popup-service',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

When I put a break point in the map-draw controller:

```
//app/controllers/map-draw.js
var popup = this.get('mapPopup').create({feature: this.sketch});
```

I can get the popup (debugger):

[image: debug (this.get('mapPopup')]

I can create the element:
[image: createElement]

But if I try to get the view controller, it has not been injected:
[image: get('controller')]

I tried to call get('mapPopup') several time in the ma-draw controller but I always get the same view instance (same id)

I'll try to see in the render helper how controller injection works...

**EDIT: some input from reading the source code of ember.js**

in the file *ember.js/packages/ember-application/lib/system/application.js*

````
    ```javascript
    App.inject(<full_name or type>, <property name>, <full_name>)
    App.inject('route', 'source', 'source:main')
    App.inject('route:application', 'email', 'model:email')
    ```
    It is important to note that injections can only be performed on
    classes that are instantiated by Ember itself. Instantiating a class
    directly (via `create` or `new`) bypasses the dependency injection
    system.
    **Note:** Ember-Data instantiates its models in a unique manner, and consequently
    injections onto models (or all models) will not work as expected. Injections
    on models can be enabled by setting `Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS`
    to `true`.
    @method inject
    @param  factoryNameOrType {String}
    @param  property {String}
    @param  injectionName {String}
  **/
  inject() {
    this.registry.injection(...arguments);
  },
````

That line particularly gave me a big hint:

> Instantiating a class directly (via `create` or `new`) bypasses the dependency injection system.

I tried to import the view in the controller:
import MapPopup from '../views/map-popup';

and I instantiated the popup like that:

```
var popup = MapPopup.create({feature: this.sketch});
```

Now, I get a new instance of the view everytime I call *create*
I still don't have the controller though...

**EDIT: After reading the render helper**
I managed to set the map-popup controller like this:

```
//app/controller/map-draw.js
var popup = MapPopup.create({feature: this.sketch});
var controller = this.container.lookup('controller:map-popup');
controller.setProperties({
  target: this,
  parentController: this
});
popup.set('controller', controller);
```

Now, I can call any function from the popup controller, but I kind of don't like that at all. I would love if someone with good knowledge of ember.js could direct me on this before I call controller factory to get different instances of the controller...

**EDIT: Best solution I can come up with**

After reading this:

> if you are creating views outside the context of a parentView (this
>   may not be recommended, but it is happening) you will want to make
>   sure to instantiate your view via the container itself.
>
> this.container.lookup('view:apple') // will provide a instance of
>   apple view.

[stefanpenner / default_container_deprecation.md](https://gist.github.com/stefanpenner/5627411)

I went in the source code and read that:

````
 /**
    Given a fullName return a corresponding instance.

    The default behaviour is for lookup to return a singleton instance.
    The singleton is scoped to the container, allowing multiple containers
    to all have their own locally scoped singletons.

    ```javascript
    var container = new Container();
    container.register('api:twitter', Twitter);

    var twitter = container.lookup('api:twitter');

    twitter instanceof Twitter; // => true

    // by default the container will return singletons
    var twitter2 = container.lookup('api:twitter');
    twitter2 instanceof Twitter; // => true

    twitter === twitter2; //=> true
    ```

    If singletons are not wanted an optional flag can be provided at lookup.

    ```javascript
    var container = new Container();
    container.register('api:twitter', Twitter);

    var twitter = container.lookup('api:twitter', { singleton: false });
    var twitter2 = container.lookup('api:twitter', { singleton: false });

    twitter === twitter2; //=> false
    ```

    @method lookup
    @param {String} fullName
    @param {Object} options
    @return {any}
  */
  lookup: function(fullName, options)
````

I ended up doing this in my controller:

```
//app/contorllers/map-draw.js
var popup = _this.container.lookup('view:map-popup', { singleton: false });
var ctrl = _this.container.lookup('controller:map-popup', { singleton: false });
popup.set('controller', ctrl);
popup.createElement(); // create the div element
```

The *singleton: false* is really important, without it all the popups would render the same content (the last added)

**EDIT I discovered about child views and might give it a look today**

[Understanding the view layers](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/understanding-ember/the-view-layer/)